# python keyword search in csv comments

Tags: python, pandas, csv, search

I am trying to do multiple keyword search in csv file just in column comments. for some reason when I try to search I get this error message 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'description'

for example

```
table1.csv
id_Acco,     user_name,       post_time      comments     
1543603,     SameDavie ,      "2020/09/06"   The car in the house  
1543595,     Johntim,         "2020/09/11"   You can filter the data
1558245,     ACAtesdfgsf ,    "2020/09/19"   if you’re looking at a ship 
1558245,     TDRtesdfgsf ,    "2020/09/19"   you can filter the table to show
```

Output

```
id_Acco,     user_name,       post_time      comments     
1543603,     SameDavie ,      "2020/09/06"   The car in the house  
1543595,     Johntim,         "2020/09/11"   You can filter the data
1558245,     TDRtesdfgsf ,    "2020/09/19"   you can filter the table to show
```

code

```
df = pd.read_csv('table1.csv')
df[df.description.str.contains('house| filter | table | car')]
df.to_csv('forum_fraud_date_keyword.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code for filtering using regex by [`.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
df = df.loc[df.comments.str.contains(r'\b(?:house|filter|table|car)\b')]
```

Here, we use r-string for including regex meta-characters.

We use `\b` to encompass the 4 target words so that it will only match whole word instead of partial string.  E.g. `carmen` won't be matched with `car`, `tablespoon` would not match `table`.  If you want to match partial string, you can remove the pair of `\b` in the regex above.

You can look at this [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ieo2KL/1/) for the matching demo.

Result:

```
print(df)


   id_Acco,     user_name,     post_time                          comments
0  1543603,    SameDavie ,  "2020/09/06"              The car in the house
1  1543595,       Johntim,  "2020/09/11"           You can filter the data
3  1558245,  TDRtesdfgsf ,  "2020/09/19"  you can filter the table to show
```